# Visual studio 11 .xaml design view error

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012

Ok, first off I am confused on what is happening, I open up the code Blankpage.xml and click design view, but when I click on design view I get an error that says this

```
    System.UnauthorizedAccessException

       Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))



        at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.DirectInvoke[T](WaitHandle abort, Func`1 func)
          at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TResult,TValue]         (RemoteHandle`1 targetObject, Func`1 func)
       at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TResult,TValue](RemoteHandle`1 targetObject, Func`2 func)
    at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor)
      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.CreateDesignerViewInfo(IIsolationTarget isolationTarget, IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationTokenSource cancelSource)


          System.UnauthorizedAccessException
          Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

              Server stack trace: 
                at          Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.CallQueue.WaitForCompletion(BlockingCall call)
        at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.CallQueue.Invoke(BlockingCall call)
         at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.CallQueue.Invoke[T](Func`1 func, WaitHandle aborted)
              at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalIn[TResult](IRemoteObject targetObject, Func`1 func)
               at         Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IRemoteHostSourceItem remoteItem, IRemoteHostTextEditor remoteEditor)
          at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
         at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

       Exception rethrown at [0]: 
      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
         at            Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IRemoteHostSourceItem remoteItem, IRemoteHostTextEditor remoteEditor)
         at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass8.           <Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IDesignerService.CreateDesigner>b__7(IRemoteDesignerService d)
          at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.<>c__DisplayClass4`2.<MarshalOut>b__3()
            at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.DirectInvoke[T](WaitHandle abort, Func`1 func)
```

... I cant figure out what is wrong, This happened right after I deployed my project as a windows 8 metro application

Comment: Where on your computer is Visual Studio installed?  Did you install the Windows 8 Beta as a clean install or did you upgrade from Windows 7? Have you installed the [April 2012 Update](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29297)?

Comment: I did the windows 7 to windows 8 and It was working fine, when I was first using it, it wasn't until I debugged the app that it happened, also I installed it on April 15th so Idk if I did the update or not

Comment: Did you figure out what was causing this? I'm running into it now.